# Mouse drag in embbeded Win32 window

Tags: winapi, dialog, event-handling, mouseevent

In a Qt dialog I have an embedded native Win32 window. As in any standard Win32, I define my own message queue, where, per default, I forward all events to the parent window, and in case an event of interest arrives, I perform some extra work.

My problem is that when I press the left mouse button, then I get the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` as expected, but if I keep it pressed, then I get no more mouse clicks events, that is, I get the `WM_MOUSE` messages, but the mask (`wParam`), or calling `GetKeyState`, do not indicate that the mouse key is kept pressed.

The window is created with following parameters,

```
dwExStyle = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
dwStyle &= ~(WS_BORDER| WS_CAPTION | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_THICKFRAME);
CreateWindowExW(0,"Window","Name",dwStyle,
                           0,0,512,512,
                           hwndParent,NULL,hInstance,NULL )
```

When this native window is not embedded in any dialog, it works correctly.

I could also embed this window in a .NET dialog window and observe the same problem.

Any clue what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `WM_MOUSEMOVE`? Did you try capturing the mouse first?

`WM_LBUTTONDOWN` is sent only once per click. You'll have to use a boolean to keep track of whether the button is pressed or released during the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events. Make use of the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages together to keep track of this.